# warning. ftp_pwd(). 30 is not a valid FTP Buffer resource in /home

Tags: php

I am uploading a new listing from Admin Panel. After submit it says data has been recorded, but the photos do not upload and I get a warning for the photo uploads. If I upoad 3 photos I get 3 warning messages such as

warning. ftp_pwd(). 30 is not a valid FTP Buffer resource in /home/xxx/public_html/admin/classes/ftpClass.php on line 49.

warning. ftp_pwd(). 31 is not a valid FTP Buffer resource in /home/xxx/public_html/admin/classes/ftpClass.php on line 49.

warning. ftp_pwd(). 32 is not a valid FTP Buffer resource in /home/xxx/public_html/admin/classes/ftpClass.php on line 49.

Here is the page code.

```
<?

class FTP{
    var $ftp_host           = "localhost";
    var $ftp_portu          = 21 ;
    var $ftp_kullanici_adi = "xxx_1";
    var $ftp_sifre          = "xxxxxx";
    var $ftp_timeout        = 2700;//saniye cinsinden

    var $ftp_id;
    var $ftp_login_id;
    var $ftp_onaylanan_uzantilar = array();
    var $ftp_hedef_dosya;
    var $ftp_kaynak_dosya;
    var $ftp_transfer_tipi  = FTP_BINARY; //FTP_ASCII,FTP_BINARY
    var $mesaj              = "";

    function baglan(){

    $this->ftp_id       = @ftp_connect($this->ftp_host,$this->ftp_portu);
    $this->ftp_login_id = @ftp_login($this->ftp_id, $this->ftp_kullanici_adi,  $this->ftp_sifre);

    if((!$this->ftp_login_id) || (!$this->ftp_id)){
    $this->kapat();
    return 0;
    }else{
    return 1;
    }
    }

    function dizin_sil($dizin_adi){
    if(@ftp_rmdir($this->ftp_id,$dizin_adi)){
    return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
    }

    function nerdeyim(){
    return ftp_pwd($this->ftp_id);
    }

    function dizine_git($yeni_dizin){
    if(@ftp_chdir($this->ftp_id, $yeni_dizin)){
    return 1;
    }else{
    return 0;
    }
    }

    function dizin_olustur($dizin_adi, $chmode){
    if(strlen($dizin_adi) > 0){
    $yeni_dizin_adi = $this->ismini_degistir($dizin_adi);
    //$this->dizine_git("/");
    if(@ftp_mkdir($this->ftp_id, $yeni_dizin_adi)){
    //@ftp_chmod($yeni_dizin_adi, $chmode);hata veriyor
    return 1;
    }else{
    return 0;
    }
    }
    }

    function dizin_chmod($dizin_adi, $chmode){
    if(strlen($dizin_adi) > 0){
    if( ftp_chmod($this->ftp_id,$chmode,$dizin_adi) ){
    return 1;
    }else{
    return 0;
    }
    }
    }

    function uzantisi_nedir($dosya_adi){
    $dizi = explode(".", $dosya_adi);
    $dizi = array_reverse($dizi);
    return $dizi[0];
    }

    function uzanti_onayla($uzanti){
    if(in_array($uzanti, $this->ftp_onaylanan_uzantilar)){
    return 1;
    }else{
    return 0;
    }
    }

    function ismini_degistir($eski_adi){
    $harf_dizisi = array("Ç" => "C",
                             "Ğ" => "G",
                             "İ" => "I",
                             "Ö" => "O",
                             "Ş" => "S",
                             "Ü" => "U",
                             "ç" => "c",
                             "ğ" => "g",
                             "ı" => "i",
                             "ö" => "o",
                             "ş" => "s",
                             "ü" => "u" );
        foreach($harf_dizisi as $kaynak => $hedef):
            $eski_adi = @eregi_replace($kaynak, $hedef, $eski_adi);
        endforeach;

        $yeni_adi = @eregi_replace(" ", "_", $eski_adi);
        $yeni_adi = @strtolower($yeni_adi);

        return $yeni_adi;
    }

    function yukle($adi,$dosya){

        $yukleme = @ftp_put($this->ftp_id, $adi, $dosya, $this->ftp_transfer_tipi);
        if ($yukleme){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

   function kapat(){   @ftp_close($this->ftp_id);    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: [`eregi_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi-replace.php) *"**Warning**

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged."*